# Drawing an A using a single GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP

Tags: opengl

Is this possible? (I know, it is, but I can't do it.)

```
void drawScene(void)
{  

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   if (isWire) 
       glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
   else
   glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
   glVertex3f(10,10,0);
   glVertex3f(20,10,0);

   glVertex3f(30,80,0);
   glVertex3f(40,70,0);

   glVertex3f(50,80,0);
   glVertex3f(60,10,0);

   glVertex3f(70,10,0);
   glEnd();

   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);

   glEnd();

   glFlush();
}
```

There is my attempt, although my next idea would be to bridge the legs of the A. But I would like to do it in one single strip.

Comment: I think this would do it: http://s13.postimg.org/5fgh0y9tz/image.png http://s23.postimg.org/4g5a3f9u3/image.png You'll have to work out the math yourself, I was just doodling to find the rough solution.

Comment: You could use degenerate triangles to move "current position" around without introducing any visible geometry. Look it up.

Comment: Draco18s. Thank. You. I had a look, to be honest, a better understanding of how GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP works was in order. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

With help from my friend geometry :)

```
void drawScene(void)
{  

   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   if (isWire) 
       glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
   else
   glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

     // Draw a triangle strip.
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
      glVertex3f(10.0, 10.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(20.0, 10.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(12.0, 30.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(22.0, 30.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(17.0, 80.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(26.0, 70.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(35.0, 80.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(31.0, 40.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(42.0, 35.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(23.0, 40.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(25.0, 35.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(21.9, 30.0,0.0); 

  glVertex3f(42.0, 35.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(32.0, 30.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(46.0, 10.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3f(36.5, 10.0, 0.0);
   glEnd();


   glFlush();
}
```